# How to put marker on vector layer with lat/lon on QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a vector layer, and bunch of lat/lon values. I want to put markers on the vector layer for each lat/lon pair. I have never used QGIS, would you help with it.

Comment: Needs to ask from the @user3335418 if it is duplicate. For the referred old question the best answer was to use the manual "Numerical digitize" tool. Answers which suggest to use CSV import seem to be given because the question was misunderstood.

Comment: Either way, the existing thread shows two possible ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must convert the lat/lon values into another vector layer first. Save your lat/lon data into comma separated text file together with the attributes your want to include and use the import tool that is in Layer - Add delimited text layer. There is a tutorial here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html